# 3d Alternative for D3DXSPRITE for billboarding

Tags: c++, directx

I am looking to billboard a sun image in my **3d** world (directx 9).

Creating a `D3DXSPRITE` is great in some cases, but it is only a **2d** object and can not exist in my "world" as a **3d** object.  What is an alternative method for billboarding, similar to `d3dxsprite`?  How can I implement it?

The only alternative I have currently found is this link: http://www.two-kings.de/tutorials/dxgraphics/dxgraphics17.html which does not seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the center of your object vCenter.  The object has a width and height of (w,h).

Firstly you need your camera to billboard vector.  This is calculated as vCamToCen = normalise( vCamera - vCenter ).

You then need an appropriate rough up vector.  This can be extracted from the view matrix (handily described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee415399(VS.85).aspx), ie the second column).  You can then calculate the side vector by doing vSide = vCamToCen x vUp.  Then calculate the REAL up vector by doing vUp = vCamToCen x vSide. Where 'x' is a cross product.

You now have all the info you need to do your billboarding.

You can then form your 4 verts as follows.

```
const float halfW = w / 2.0f;
const float halfH = h / 2.0f;

const D3DXVECTOR3 vHalfSide = vSide * halfW;
const D3DXVECTOR3 vHalfUp = vUp  * halfH;

vertex[0].pos = vCenter;
vertex[1].pos = vCenter;
vertex[2].pos = vCenter;
vertex[3].pos = vCenter;

vertex[0].pos -= vHalfSide;
vertex[0].pos -= vHalfUp;

vertex[1].pos += vHalfSide;
vertex[1].pos -= vHalfUp;

vertex[2].pos += vHalfSide;
vertex[2].pos += vHalfUp;

vertex[3].pos -= vHalfSide;
vertex[3].pos += vHalfUp;
```

Build your 2 triangles out of those verts and pass it through your pipeline as normal (ie with your normal view and projection matrices).